# ffmpeg: from eac3 7.1 to 8 discrete wavs (but with atempo=1.001 applied on each output channel)

Tags: ffmpeg

```bash
ffmpeg  
-hide_banner  
-i 'audio_extracted.eac3'
-filter_complex "channelsplit=channel_layout=7.1[FL][FR][FC][LFE] 
[SL][SR][BL][BR]"
-map "[FL]" -c:a pcm_s24le "output_audio_FL.wav"   
-map "[FR]" -c:a pcm_s24le "output_audio_FR.wav"  
-map "[FC]" -c:a pcm_s24le "output_audio_FC.wav"  
-map "[LFE]" -c:a pcm_s24le "output_audio_LFE.wav"  
-map "[SL]" -c:a pcm_s24le "output_audio_SL.wav"  
-map "[SR]" -c:a pcm_s24le "output_audio_SR.wav"  
-map "[BL]" -c:a pcm_s24le "output_audio_BL.wav" 
-map "[BR]" -c:a pcm_s24le "output_audio_BR.wav"
```

Where I put this ?

```
-filter:a atempo=1.001
```

Thanks

PS:
Source file (from MediaInfo):

```
Audio  
Format : E-AC-3 
Format/Info : Enhanced AC-3  
Commercial name : Dolby Digital Plus  
Format profile : Blu-ray Disc  
Duration : 1 h 43 min  
Bit rate mode : Constant  
Bit rate : 896 kb/s  
Channel(s) : 8 channels  
Channel layout : L R C LFE Ls Rs Lb Rb
```

Comment: For the input: `-filter_complex "atempo=1.001,channelsplit...`, and in case it must be applied for the output: `"...channelsplit=channel_layout=7.1[FL0][FR0][FC0][LFE0][SL0][SR0][BL0][BR0];[FL0]atempo=1.001[FL];[FR0]atempo=1.001[FR];[FC0]atempo=1.001[FC];..."`

Comment: Great! thanks so much!